# O(1) distinct elements in an array implies?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Could someone explain the following question -

Given the following statement viz. Consider an input array a[1..n] of arbitrary numbers. It is given that
the array has only O(1) distinct elements. What does the statement imply ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear whether you're looking for what it _means_ or what it _implies_. The given answer says what the statement that the array has O(1) distinct elements means; but one thing that it implies, for instance, is that some element appears O(n) times. There are various other implications, too; for instance, it can be sorted in time O(n), etc. Can you be at all more specific about what you're after?

Comment: I guess what I was looking for is that O(1) distinct elements in an array implies that there would be a fixed number of distinct elements, no matter the size of the array(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, it means no matter what the size of the array is (namely, no matter what $n$ is), it will have no more than a fixed constant number of distinct elements. This assumes that you know what the term $O(1)$ means. If not, ask for clarification.